# Can someone explain the bug in this python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is non-working and working code which generates a list of lists.

Example 1 does not work correctly, it repeats the last list appended over and over.

Example 2, where I replaced delete with creating a new list does work correctly.

```
# Example 1, this does not work correctly
l1 = []
l2 = []
x = 0
for n in range(0,3):
    del l1[:] # deleting all list elements
    for i in range(0,3):
        l1.append(x)
        x+=1
    l2.append(l1)
print(l2)


# Example 2, this works correctly
l2 = []
x = 0
for n in range(0,3):
    l1 = [] # creating the list each loop through
    for i in range(0,3):
        l1.append(x)
        x+=1
    l2.append(l1)
print(l2)
```

Answer (score 4):

In your first example, `l1` is the same list object the entire time.  When you do `l2.append(l1)`, you insert a reference to this `l1` object into `l2`.  When the loop restarts and you delete everything in `l1`, you also delete everything in the list inside `l2`, because that is the same list.  You are appending the same list object to `l2` multiple times, so every time you clear it, you clear every list in `l2`.

In the second example, you create a separate list object every time.  Each list object is thus independent, and clearing one doesn't affect the others.

Answer (score 3):

Visualization of #1 code - http://goo.gl/6ICqo

`l2` and `l1` refer to the same object (list). When you delete all the elements of the list, the change is reflected in `l2` and `l1`.

Visualization of #2 code - http://goo.gl/fkoqh

Here, when the code executes `l1 = []`, `l1`'s reference gets re-assigned. But `l2`'s elements keep referring to the original object.

Comment: This is incredibly useful. Thank you.

Comment: @jbiondo - Welcome. You should upvote an answer that you find useful.